# C - Mutex attributes

Tags: c, mutex, recursive-mutex

Can I create and use only one mutex attribute to initialize multiple recursive mutexes? Or do I have to create one mutex attribute for each mutex I want to create?
Basically I the following code correct?

```
int err;
int bufferLength = 10;
pthread_mutexattr_t recursiveAttr;
pthread_mutex_t mutexes[bufferLength];

for(int index = 0; index < bufferLength; index++){
    err = pthread_mutex_init(&mutexes[i], &recursiveAttr);
    if(err != 0){
        perror("Error initializing the mutex");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same attribute object for multiple mutexes.

Note however, that the `pthread_mutexattr_t` object you're using must be initialized itself. To initialize a `pthread_mutexattr_t` you must use [`pthread_mutexattr_init`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutexattr_init.html) (and eventually, `pthread_mutexattr_destroy`), both of which should be done *once*. Your current code makes no such calls, and should do so to be compliant.